# Force w3wp.exe process to start in 32-bit mode

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've created an ASP WebForm application that requires "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to be set to true.  When I set the site up in IIS I set "Enable 32-Bit Applications" true, but when I look at the Task Manager I'm not seeing the *32 next to the w3wp.exe process that starts up. And when I browse to the site I'm getting "Service Unavailable - HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable." as the App Pool stops within IIS.

How can I force the w3wp.exe process to start in 32 bit mode?

**EDIT-** The machine in question is a 64-bit Windows Server 2012 R2 in case that matters

**EDIT 2-** I found a link to http://www.manasbhardwaj.net/running-32-bit-web-application-iis-8/ Which references issues wile Running Sharepoint 2013, Which is running on the web server. It applied the changes, and now when I run the site I get a configuration Error regarding framework versions.

I find it odd b/c the app pool still is not showing the *32 next to it, but it didn't crash when starting the site.

I'm going to ensure the latest .NET framework is installed now.

**EDIT 3-** Looks like I need to run a couple of updates on the machine in order to install the latest .NET framework. The .NET framework my site uses is 4.6.1, Is this version Stable enough to run on a Live WebServer running SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Does this helps? https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2009/10/21/force-net-application-to-run-in-32bit-process-on-64bit-os/

Comment: I already have the Solution Platform target set, as well as the Context in IIS set. 

I'm hesitant to use corflags.exe or a wrapper application, as I have this site running properly on my local machine. [w3wp.exe *32 is used when I run it though my local IIS] 

And yes I have duplicated every setting from Local to my webserver to no avail....

Comment: When the app pool stops, do you see an error in the Application event log?

Comment: I get 10 "IIS-W3SVC-WP" Errors [The Module DLL 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\isapi\spnativerequestmodule.dll' could not be loaded due to a configuration problem. The current configuration only supports loading images built for a x86 processor architecture. The data field contains the error number. To learn more about this issue, including how to troubleshooting this kind of processor architecture mismatch error, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=29349.] And a couple "User Profile Services" Info Events [not enough space to put event]

Comment: IIS can have multiple application pools, so make sure you force the proper pool that runs your web app to 32 bit.